# Remove characters from both left and right of a string in PHP

Tags: php

This is an example of a string: `abcde123#ijklmn0pq`

In that string I need to print out only the numbers (the `123` sequence), and remove the letters (from both left and right) and the **hashtag (`#`) to be removed** as well.

The hashtag (`#`) is always included in the string.

The hashtag (`#`) is always positioned to the right of the characters that need to be printed;

The hashtag (`#`) is always positioned to the left of the characters that need to be removed;

Therefore, the hashtag (`#`) can be used as a guide to remove the letters from the Right

The number of **characters in the beginning** is always equal to 5 (constant) **(to be removed);**

The number of **characters in the middle** is always different (variable) **(to be printed)**;

The number of **characters in the right** is always different (variable) **(to be removed)**;

Here's another string example, similar to the first one: `!!@@$IMPORTANT#=-=whatever`

The characters that need to be printed are the word "`IMPORTANT`"

As with the first example, what's on the left side of the hashtag (#) needs to be printed, but it's important to print only the "`IMPORTANT`" word, without the special characters "!!@@$".

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: so a regex then... like `/^.{5,5}(.*)[#].*$/` thats untested but i would imagine it would be something similar...

Comment: Hi there. There's no need to mark questions as solved - you may comment under the answer if you wish to specifically say something about it. It is optional, but upvoting other answers that look like they would work is encouraged - it is a good way of thanking the other users for their efforts.

Comment: For your information: your question was certainly accurate, in terms of what you want, but that may also be the reason for the downvotes - it appears to readers as a requirements specification for free work. When you next ask a question (and I hope you will) please show what work you have tried, and where specifically you have got stuck.

Comment: oh, i see ... thank you for your inputs, next time will do better, as you guys have suggested and will also upvote the other answers once i get some more points available for voting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$myString = '!!@@$IMPORTANT#=-=whatever';

$result = substr($myString, 5, -1);

$pos = strpos($result, '#');

$result = substr($result, 0, $pos);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexes with `preg_replace()`;

Assuming that the string you need to process is stored in `$string`:

```
preg_replace('^.{5}(.*)#.*$', '$1', $string);
```

https://www.regex101.com/r/hA8lY7/1

**First pattern explanation:**

1. `^.{5}`: matches any 5 character after the start of `$string`
2. `(.*)`: matches any N character after (1) before the first occurence of `#` (first capturing-group)
3. `#.*$`: matches `#` and any N character after (2) before the end of `$string`

**Second pattern explanation:**

1. `$1`: replaces `$string` with the first capturing-group matched in the first pattern

Answer (score 0):

Ill give a stab at this. seems pretty simple.

```
function choppy($choppy) {

    $nstr = substr($choppy, 5,strlen($choppy)); //chop first 5
    $pos = strpos($nstr, "#"); //Find the position of the hash tag

    return substr($nstr, 0, $pos); //we only need the stuff before it...
}

echo choppy('!!@@$IMPORTANT#=-=whatever');
echo "\n";
echo choppy('abcde123#ijklmn0pq');
```

Result

```
C:\Users\developer\Desktop>php test.php
IMPORTANT
123
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good but if you need a one-liner for your homework:

```
$str = '!!@@$IMPORTANT#=-=whatever';

echo substr($str, 5, strpos($str, '#')-5); //IMPORTANT
```